# Save xamlx on runtime

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I am working on a winform project which actually receive a BPMN file and translate it to a workflow .xaml file so it acts like a BPMN to Workflow Converter. So this conversion is done entirely programmatically and no designer is used. The activities should be assigned on run time so nothing is predifined. For example a bpmn file with a Start event connected to an exclusive gateway is implemented my application receive it and translate it to a start event in workflow connected to an IF Activity etc. And finally the workflow is saved as a xaml file. Thus nothing is predifined and my application design the workflow accoirding to the specifications of the bpmn file that receives. My problem is instead of a .xaml file i want .xamlx file because those workflows i will expose them from my server. I couldnt find any examples in the internet. Any ideas or approaches?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using BPMN2WF which is a prototype application for transforming BPMN models into Workflow Foundation (WF) code. For more information visit http://bpmn2wf.codeplex.com/

Comment: My question is not how to convert the bpmn controls to worfklow foundation, my question is how to convert the final convertion into xamlx file.

Comment: I think this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650555/wf4-hosting-conversion-of-self-hosting-console-app-to-service-hosted-in-iis